# How to write an operating system

Tags: linux, operating-system

I am a Chinese girl,i am an senior student,so i need to do the graduation design.so,i want to write a simple operating system which just can run and do some easily thing.I hope you can provide some useful books and website for learning in order to finish this work.also i just have half of a year to finish it.thank you very much.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, most operating system semester projects take a minimal open-source operating system such as MINIX and add/redesign one major component, such as the task scheduler.  Which is a major undertaking but still much more attainable than completing an entire OS.

Comment: http://osdev.org/ is a good start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to define, what exactly means - simple operating system:

1. Will this system work only on a specific hardware - for instance embedded platform?
2. What userspace programs you would like to use?
3. Are you going to use some components from Linux?
4. Do you want to implement device drivers?

There are a lot of questions about it. First of all, you have to take into account, that even if you write own filesystem, 
you have to write a program which is able to format your disk according to your filesystem structue etc. 
The same situation regards to libraries like libc for instance. So first thing to consider is, what applications will be able to run on this system 
and if you want to write them, or you want to use applications which are intended for others system. In the case of second option, 
your system has supports, at least  part of Linux system (if you want to start Linux apps) calls, what is not easy to do, especially
 when we take such system calls like epoll, select and so on. I think that if you have only half a year, then write something similar to DOS.
 Then you don't have to implement own drivers to read something from disk or print something on the screen. You can look at the sources of 
bootloader (grub1) which uses bios interrupts how it is done. Next implement easy memory management and process scheduling. Then maybe very basic 
filesystem. This is what I would personally focus on, but still not enough information.

Comment: Firstly.thank you very much.I want this system work in x86.I want to use some components from Linux and also want to implement device drivers.but something like you said that i just have half of a year.maybe it is very difficulty to finish it.